# Using a Wacom Tablet in Blender

Tags: sculpting

I'm a complete noob when it comes to sculpting. I recently began CGCookie's The Fundamentals of Sculpting course...

...and I can't figure out how to make my Wacom tablet work with Blender. It "left-clicks" just fine (yay, I figured it out! :-P), but I've been unable to figure out how to tumble around the scene...or to select objects...

...embarrassing, I know...

So, if anybody would mind helping a poor naive soul, could somebody please point out how to use these Blender operations that normally are operated with right- and middle-mouse clicks using a Wacom tablet?

Comment: What OS are you using? It is slightly different if using a Amc, but here on Linux I go to User Preferences in Blender, under Input tab choose Emulate 3 Button Mouse. Then I have the ability to use my pen button to rotate view, Shift+pen button to pan and Ctrl+pen button to zoom. My pen has the pen button set to RMB, so some of the things that need a roll of the mmb end up needing me to input on the keyboard.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Sierra v10.12.6. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the actual question.

Comment: I have a MacPro at work, and same OS. I notice there some differences, so you might try the 3 button emulation and experiment with the ctrl,alt, shift keys there. I don't think Cmd works but I am not at work to check.

Comment: Once you figure it out, come back and post as an answer so that it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wacom has extra software provided with it's tablets where you can setup the tablet and pen buttons. This application is called "Wacom tablet settings" on Windows. Since you are working with macOS, you will probably find help right [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141119051701/https://support.apple.com/kb/PH16652).

Answer (score 4):

I use Wacom Tablet for blender with following buttons:
Tip is simple click.
Lower side button is Middle Click.
Higher side button is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> click.

Works like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What works for me using a wacom tablet is to enable "emulate 3 button mouse".

That way I can draw with one hand, and with the other I press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and press and move the sytuls to Zoom in or out.

To rotate press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press on the stylus.

To pan press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and move by pressing the stylus.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will let you erase without changing the tool.

To roll the view you need to create a new keyboard binding so that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and the <kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> on the mouse.